# D3.js spawn new circles at fixed time intervals with forceSimulation

Tags: d3.js

Hi I am trying to spawn new circles in a set time interval (e.g., double the amount of existing circles every ten seconds) with D3.forceSimulation. I am using forceSimulation to make sure the circles do not overlap. My goal is to also have the new circles spawn in a position near the existing circles.

My initial approach is to append new {} elements into the nodes array using a setInterval function. Basically check the length of the nodes array every ten seconds and append new {} elements so that the new length of the array is double the previous length.

However, I don't think I am understanding/using nodes and d3.forceSimulation correctly. In the code below I see five circles appearing and moving away from each other. But I didn't pass any x or y positions to the circle elements that are joined to the nodes data? Are default/random positions being assigned to the circles?

I know if I add .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2)) the five circles will appear near the center of the screen before moving away. But I'm not sure how d3.forceSimulation is setting the initial positions of the five circles when they spawn in.

```
 var nodes = [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
  .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody()) 
  .on('tick', ticked);

  function ticked() {
  var u = d3.select('svg')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(nodes)

  u.enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', 5)
    .merge(u)
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
      return d.x
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
      return d.y
    })

  u.exit().remove()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are default position which are assigned to the circles.
Here is a quote from d3js [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-force):

> The position ⟨x,y⟩ and velocity ⟨vx,vy⟩ may be subsequently modified
>   by forces and by the simulation. If either vx or vy is NaN, the
>   velocity is initialized to ⟨0,0⟩. If either x or y is NaN, the
>   position is initialized in a phyllotaxis arrangement, so chosen to
>   ensure a deterministic, uniform distribution around the origin.

Comment: So if I understand the docs correctly: when I append more {} elements into the nodes array, the default positions assigned to the new circles/nodes will also be initialized in a "phyllotaxis" arrangement. Therefore, the default positions are never being assigned randomly across the screen.